# Make content of ::before & ::after able for selecting with the mouse

Tags: css

Is there any way to make *content* of the pseudo elements ::*before* & ::*after* able for selecting with the mouse as it available with another text of the page?

I have something like this:

```
.nick::before {
  content: ' <';
}

.nick::after {
  content: '> ';
}
```

`<span>[09:42:43]<span class="nick">SomeUser</span>AnotherUser: blah blah</span>`

Then I select it and copy, I got: `[09:42:43]SomeUserAnotherUser: blah blah`

Needed: `[09:42:43] <SomeUser> AnotherUser: blah blah`

I want to get CSS solution if it possible.

Comment: css generated content cannot be selected nor seen by google for instance

Answer (score 0):

[THIS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/) is a nice article about the :after and :before pseudo-elements.

Given the text (and GCyrillus' comment above), these pseudo-elements are not "accessible" in the DOM, so you wouldn't be able to "click" on them with an HTML or js/jQuery "click".

So I wonder about a plan "B".

Why can't you add them directly as HTML?

If the names are coming from a DB, couldn't you just add "<" and ">" to the php or js?

I probably am missing your point.

Comment: > couldn't you just add "<" and ">"

– Yes, I can, but the page contains jabber chatlogs and have one feature – style changing by user. It works by the simplest way:

`function changeStyle() {`
 `$("head link[rel='stylesheet']").href = "css/{file}.css".format({file: document.forms.style.css.value});`
`}`

I didn't want to make it more difficult way.

Comment: And yes, I know what ::before & ::after are not accessible in the DOM. But I was hoping that there is some kind of CSS-hack or maybe some simple js-workaround.